# odoo with kubernetes is not using my default addons

Tags: kubernetes, odoo, persistent-volumes

I have a serious problem. I am trying to deploy an odoo instance. Before I mount a volume for my custom addons, when i create my odoo database i can see all default applications appearing. But, when I tried to mount my custom addons volume, creating a new database doesn't show me any default application in the home page. When I restore an existing database that uses my custom addons, it can read all my custom addons, but it can't read the default addons of odoo.
This is how i declared my volumes in my deployment:
pv-odoo is for mounting my custom addons and odoo-conf is for mounting my odooconfiguration file

```
      volumeMounts:
      - name: odoo-pvc
        mountPath: /var/lib/odoo

      - name: pv-odoo
        mountPath: /mnt/extra-addons/10.0

      - name: odoo-conf
        mountPath: /etc/odoo

  volumes:
  - name: odoo-pvc
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: odoo-pvc

  - name: pv-odoo
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: odoo-data

  - name: odoo-conf
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: odoo-conf-pvc
```

this is my manifest to mount my custom addons:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: odoo-data
  namespace: odoo
  labels:
    id: odoo-data
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 700Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/bitnami/odoo/addons"

  ---

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: odoo-data
  namespace: odoo
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      id: odoo-data
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 700Mi
```

Please,I am waiting for your help guys.

Comment: Could you please paste the logs for your specific errors?

Comment: thnx for your comment, I accually fixed this when mounting my aadons in this path "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/extra". Now my icons application appear of my addons but I don't understand why some icons of my extra addons don't appear.